# How to configure Thunderbird, remove Thunderbird from global appmenu e-mail icon

Tags: thunderbird, evolution, appmenu

I am a frequent user of Ubuntu and recently upgraded from Lucid to Ubuntu 11.10. I was not able to properly configure Thunderbird, so I switched to Evolution.

First of all what I want is smooth way to configure Thunderbird with all features enabled, like global address list and calendar setting.

I also want to know how to remove Thunderbird from global appmenu email icon,
and how to insert Evolution email icon in its place.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! The site works best if you ask each of these questions separately, thanks! :)

Answer (score 2):

Let's start with remove Thunderbird from dash main menu and insert Evolution instead.

You have to set Evolution as default Email client:
go to System Settings / System info.
Click on Default Applications and select Evolution as default E-mail client [image]

When you next open the dash menu you will see the Evolution icon.

For a calender integration into Thunderbird install the lightning package:

```
sudo apt-get install xul-ext-lightning
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting up Thunderbird is very easy.  You must make sure that you chose imap and not PPP.  Everything is automatic.

Comment: Thanks for your Answer but the problem is its not downloading Global address list as well colander setting.